# Selecting more informative frames from an audio signal

Tags: matlab, audio, signals

[image: Onsets in the audio signal]

I am computing onsets in an audio signal, which is shown in the attached image. The red dots correspond to the local maxima of the onset curve envelope.

Now what I want is to just take one of the onsets at places where multiple local maximas are very close(in terms of time) to each other.(Look at the two local maximas near 7.5s, which are very close to each other). I want just one of them.

What would be a good strategy / algorithm to do so?

Comment: What means close? Close in time or close in aplitude?

Comment: Close in time, not amplitude

Comment: Okay, think now I understood your question. How do you get your onsets? If `findpeaks` is used it has a `MinPeaksDistance` option to define a minimal spacing. You want to select the peaks with the largest amplitude if two are close together?

Comment: Yes, I would want the largest peak if there are multiple peaks close together. But how to I define what "close together" means? How close it "close together", that is the question ?

Comment: I think that would depend on your application. You could get the two closest peaks (or the n closest), or you could set a closeness threshold either using a static value or a statistically determined value. You could do a combination of both.